# 'datetime2' error when using entity framework in VS 2010 .net 4.0

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

Getting this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

My entity objects all line up to the DB objects.

I found only a single reference to this error via Google:

[Google result](http://ramonaeid.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!A77704F1DB999BB0!182.entry)

After reading this, I remember that we *did* add 2 fields and then updated the entity model from VS 2010.  I'm not sure what he means by "hand coding" the differences.  I don't see any.

All I'm doing in code is populating the entity object and then saving. (I also populate the new fields in code)  I populated the date field with `DateTime.Now`..

The important part of the code is this:  `ctx.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);`

The database is SQL Server 2008.

***Thoughts?***

The rest of the error:

> at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
>   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
>   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
>   at SafariAdmin.Site.WebServices.SpeciesPost.SaveOrUpdateSpecies(String sid, String fieldName, String authToken) in SpeciesPost.svc.cs: line 58
>   at SafariAdmin.TestHarness.Tests.Site.WebServices.SpeciesPostSVC_Tester.SaveNewSpecies() in SpeciesPostSVC_Tester.cs: line 33
>   --SqlException
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
>   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)

Comment: The link you added on your question is now dead :/

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Entity framework handles all the dates as a Datetime2, so, if your fields in the database are Datetime, this could be a problem.
We had the same problem here, and from what we found, populating all the date fields and changing the datatype, are the most commom solutions

Comment: I was a bonehead.  I didn't populate all my date fields (apparently I had 2)

Comment: I can't judge you, our case was exaclty the same... even the solution

Comment: Regarding EF - wouldn't it make more sense that it used the Date type that is used by the database table it is mapped to instead of arbitrarily assuming everyone should be using DateTime2?  And really DateTime2?? - they couldn't just upgrade DateTime they had to create a new datatype and the ingeniously added a 2 to it?

Comment: Is there a way to find out which column is not being populated from the Exception, I can't seem to find the column name, makes debugging a pain

Comment: @jamiebarrow Not that I remember.. It's been a long time, but I think I went the old trial and error way to find the culprit :(

Comment: Just adding a finer point to Tejo's answer. Entity Framework doesn't treat _all_ dates as Datetime2, just those outside the normal SQL datetime range (January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999) or uninitialized DateTime fields. I know it's still an annoying EF design error. Choices are: initialize your DateTime field; change datatypes to Datetime2; make the field nullable in the database and Nullable<DateTime> in your code so you can represent an uninitialized value.

Comment: It fixed my cramped situation while coding.

Comment: This answer is misleading and wrong. See @Suncat2000's comment.

Comment: "make the field nullable in the database and Nullable<DateTime> in your code" is not a valid choice, @Suncat2000, EF still generates `datetime2` conversion.

Comment: @hristo Read my comment. Nullable is perfectly valid for uninitialized DateTimes, which was the original problem. EF generates datetime for values within the normal SQL range and datetime2 for values outside it.

Answer (score 50):

If you are using Code First you must declare any optional `DateTime` property as `DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>`. Unset `DateTime` objects can cause issues.

If the property is nullable in the database and a standard `DateTime` in code (not `DateTime?`), ADO.NET will send an insert command with a date of 0001-01-01 (not `NULL`), but the minimum SQL DateTime value is 1753-01-01, causing an error. If your `DateTime` property in the code is nullable (e.g. `DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>`), the insert command is will attempt to insert a `NULL` instead of an out-of-range date.

Comment: Fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 13):

Use that SQL script to convert all the columns from datetime to `datetime2`. It skips all the tables contains 'aspnet' for your convenience.

```
DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(1024)
DECLARE @TBL AS NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @COL AS NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @NUL AS BIT

DECLARE CUR CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT  SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)+'.'+t.name, c.name, c.is_nullable
    FROM    sys.tables AS t
    JOIN    sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    JOIN    information_schema.columns i ON i.TABLE_NAME = t.name 
                                        AND i.COLUMN_NAME = c.name
    WHERE   i.data_type = 'datetime' and t.name not like '%aspnet%'

    ORDER BY t.name, c.name

OPEN CUR
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @TBL, @COL, @NUL
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @TBL 
        + ' ALTER COLUMN [' + @COL + '] datetime2' 
        + (CASE WHEN @NUL=1 THEN '' ELSE ' NOT' END) + ' NULL;'
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @TBL, @COL, @NUL
END

CLOSE CUR;
DEALLOCATE CUR;
```

It works for me!

Comment: This should have a heck of a lot more votes. This fixes most of the issues related to a column type of `datetime not null` using a `0/0/0001 00:00` date which is outside the range stored in `datetime`. This script was a massive time saver.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and solve it by put the `[Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]` attribute to related properties, like below sample:

```
 [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
 public DateTime? PropertyName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 8):

Another possible solution is to set the sql column type of the field to datetime2. this can be done using fluentapi.

```
Property(x => x.TheDateTimeField)
   .HasColumnType("datetime2");
```

**Note: This is a solution for sql server 2008 upwards as datetime2 is not available for sql server 2005 or below.**

Answer (score 5):

I know that it's an old question, but as I googled here, someone else could do the same ;-)
For ones that changing from DateTime to DateTime2 isn't an option (as for SQL2005 users), I think that in most cases is more reasonable to populate fields left empty with something like 
`(DateTime)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue`
and not with DateTime.now, as it's easier to recognize it as a "pseudo-null" value (and if it's needed convert it to a real null in a partial class of father object)

Answer (score 3):

When using Entity framework code first, declare it like this:

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastLogin { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there ModifiedTime property in your entity, which is updated on the database side only?
If so, you must use DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed (for EF CodeFirst). Also visit this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9508312/1317263

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue. This was related to the mssql version.
We made it works on all of our version with this method.

Open your edmx file with an xml editor
Find this line on the top of your file

```
<Schema Namespace="XXXXX.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2008"
```

Replace the 2008 by 2005
Save your file, recompile the project.

Hope that will help someone else in the futur.

I only tried this solution with a dbfirst approche.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in my ASP.Net MVC application.

There were two model classes in my application that had DateTime properties.

upon investigating I noticed that the DateTime property of one model was nullable i.e. to make it date of Birth optional property

the other model had DateTime Property with Required data annotation (error occurs when saving this model)

my app is code first so I resolved the issue by setting datatype as DateTime2

```
[Column(TypeName="datetime2")]
```

then I ran the migration on package manager console.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever fits in a datetime will fit in a datetime2 data type, vice versa this is not the case, you can stick a date of January 1500 in a datetime2 data type but datetime only goes back to 1753, a datetime2 column can go back all the way to the year 1. I would check what the min date that you are passing in is and if your tables have datetime2 or datetime data type columns

Answer (score 1):

After trying to solve this issue for several days I used `DateTime?` as the datatype in my model with Entity Framework Code-First instead of `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that none of the not null fields in the DB(datetime) are left out while inserting/updating. I had the same error and on inserting values to those datetime fields the issue was solved.This occurs if the not null datetime fields are not assigned a proper value.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.
On your code first, set the type of DateTime to DateTime?.
So you can work with nullable DateTime type in database.

Comment: Please explain answers clearly, a short pithy answer isn't always best.

Comment: That's not what is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

This follows on from stepanZ answer... I got this error when using `Entity Framework Code First` with `AutoMapper`.

When setting up the `AutoMapping` we have `createddt`, `updateddt`, `createdby` and `updatedby` fields which are automatically set in our `public override int SaveChanges()` function. When doing this you need to ensure you set these fields to be ignored by `AutoMapper`, otherwise the database will get updated with `null` for those fields when they are not supplied from the `View`.

My issue was that I had put the source and destination around the wrong way, therefore trying to ignore the fields when setting the `ViewModel`, instead of when setting the `Model`.

The `Mapping` looked like this when I recieved this error (note: the `cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()` on the second line is mapping the `Model` to the `ViewModel` and setting the `Ignore()`)

```
cfg.CreateMap<EventViewModel, Event>();
cfg.CreateMap<Event, EventViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CreatedBy, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CreatedDt, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.UpdatedBy, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.UpdatedDt, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

The source and destination should be ignored for a mapping from `ViewModel` To `Model` (note: The code below is correct where the `Ignore()` is placed against the mapping for the `ViewModel` to the `Model`)

```
cfg.CreateMap<Event, EventViewModel>();
cfg.CreateMap<EventViewModel, Event>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CreatedBy, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CreatedDt, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.UpdatedBy, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.UpdatedDt, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Answer (score -1):

Two solutions:

- Declare the properties in your class like below and make an update-database:

  ```
  public DateTime? MyDate {get; set;}
  ```
- Or set a date for the property in the Seed method that populates the database, no need of update-database :

  ```
  context.MyClass.AddOrUpdate(y => y.MyName,new MyClass { MyName = "Random", MyDate= DateTime.Now })
  ```

Comment: Only legal for small portion of real world. Not a real workaround.