# Default date on column

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2012-localdb

I have an entity Im updating that corresponds to a LocalDB table that includes a date column with a default applied and so Im not passing a value for the date, yet I get an error like the following

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value

I dont recall getting this kind of error (assuming I have a default on the column) when Im using SQL server.

What should I check?

Comment: make sure your model property has the datetime as  nullable, else it will pass datetime.min which is out of range for datetime

Comment: You mean on the Entity Model?

Comment: yes.. if  you set the field to allow nulls, but use a default in sql.. then your entity model should have a nullable<datetime>

Comment: That was it, thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity framework error: The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365841/entity-framework-error-the-conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-da)