# "The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value"

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am creating new entity in database using entity framework and assigning below properties which users has entered, where EndDate is nullable:

```
entity.Name = this.Name.Text;
entity.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
entity.EndDate = DateTime.Now;
entity.Depo.Id = Int32.Parse(this.Depo.SelectedValue);
```

When I save changes at this point then entity is getting saved in database. but when I add any navigational property then it is creating below exception.

```
entity.Offices.Add(new HeadOffice { Office = myoffice });
```

> "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."
>
> Stack trace:
>
> at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
>      at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)

INNER Exception:

> "The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
>   The statement has been terminated."
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Tryxxx(xxxBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, xxxBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, xxxBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, xxxBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, xxxBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
>      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586566/datetime2-error-when-using-entity-framework-in-vs-2010-net-4-0?rq=1)? How are your fields defined in your database?

Comment: The problem has been resolved. There are other dateColumn fields on Navigational tabel taht were not populated.

Comment: You can add an answer of yourself and accept that one so people will know this has been solved.