# Error of data format in editing mode asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I am facing an issue when editing an existing instance of my model Client:

```
public class Client{
    public int ClientID{get;set;}
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime dateIn{get;set;}
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditFC(Client client, Connexion connexion)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {                
            db.Entry(client).State = EntityState.Modified;
            var t = client.dateIn;

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(client);
}
```

The error that is thrown is:

> *The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.*

So I don't know what's it happening my variable is dateTime I display it as a Date and I think it is maybe the problem that is when editing it takes a Date and not a DateTime, maybe I have to do a conversion but I don't how ?

Comment: What's the value of `t` when you look at it using a debugger?

Comment: Have you seen this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3586566/1127669)?

Comment: Where exception is thrown? When you try to save changes on data context ?

Comment: yes exactly when I try to save changes