# How can one find the exact cause for a DbContext.SaveChanges exception?

Tags: entity-framework

Why does EF error interface is so unhelpful ? How can one find the exact cause for a DbContext.SaveChanges exception, when the errors tell almost nothing about the parameters involved in the exception?

One serious shortcoming of `EF` in my opinion is detecting what is causing a given exception after issuing `SaveChanges()`.

It has been long since I have been struggling with EF error interface. I once helped myself a bit by writing a [**method**](http://devrecipeshb.blogspot.co.il/2015/08/extension-method-to-flatten-entity.html) that *flattens* all the db context validation errors providing straightforward messages with Table, Column and error message for each error. Otherwise one has to dig deep in the error structures dbContext returns... I wonder why they did this this way!

In any case, to my problem: 
I perform several add operations in several entities in my dbContext, and in the end issue one single `SaveChanges()`.

Now, I `GetValidationErrors()` returns 0 errors, so no validation issues.
But `SaveChanges` throws the following exception:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated.

How does `DbContext` points out the specific cause of the error in any way when what he passes over to you is a nested labyrinth of inner objects that looks like:

[image]

?!

Comment: EF uses DateTime2 fields when it accesses/stores models.  Are you letting EF build the model, or are you mapping from an existing database?

Comment: Just found a SO question that addresses this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586566/datetime2-error-when-using-entity-framework-in-vs-2010-net-4-0

Comment: @MutantNinjaCodeMonkey: working in EF Database First mode (maps existing database)

Answer (score 0):

If it's the DbEntityValidationException you can just override the SaveChanges method and grab the error and re throw it with the errors parsed out something like this:

```
public partial class MyEntities
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        try
        {
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
                                  .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
                                  .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);
            var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("\n\r", errorMessages);

            var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, "The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);

            throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how is this different that what was mentioned above, [here](http://devrecipeshb.blogspot.co.il/2015/08/extension-method-to-flatten-entity.html)

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that link.  But I guess it will get you the same result.  So if that solution worked for you...what's the problem?

Comment: thank's for leaving some help, but that's not the issue :-) I ask: why is it this complicated to get useful/meaningful error messages from DbContext.SaveChanges exceptions ? The way you do it (like I did to collect all errors in a single structure (my provides a little more - adds field and table name involved in the error) - **does not answer** at all the problem - because one can get a DbContext.SaveChanges exception without having any errors whatsoever in EntityValidations (which makes sense, because these only provide validation errors. An exception is a runtime error, something different)

Comment: Well my guess would be that these are not true exceptions.  They are entity issues.  Meaning that a constraint could be put on a table to only allow values that begin with a letter 'a'.  Is that an error? So they needed a separate place to create this collection of issues that could arise from updating a table.  So you have exceptions that could be due to communication or clr issues and then you can have database issues.

Comment: What are you calling *not true exceptions* ? The ones from DbContext.SaveChanges ? Why, these are the only exceptions here :-) Whatever EntityValidationErrors collect, they are validation errors and not exceptions (these would go more in line with what you suggest, these are not real exceptions, they are constraint enforcement failures, and alike)

Comment: In any case, I hope you understand what my problem is and why what you posted does not help - because what you give deals only with validation problems, I want a way to efficiently extract meaningful information from DbContext.SaveChanges() exceptions, which is really not easy - sometimes I am doubtful if possible at all.