# Passing DateTime parameter to stored procedure using EF(DB first)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[select_alltypes]
    @cdin_startunstufdate1 DateTime = null,
    @cdin_startunstufdate2 DateTime = null
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        0 as shipid, 
        i.cdin_cdindexid, p.pinv_PerformaInvID,
        coalesce(i.cdin_serial, 0) as depno,
        coalesce(convert(datetime, left(convert(nvarchar, i.cdin_startunstufdate, 120), 10), 120),'-') as deidate,
        coalesce(i.cdin_goodsDesc, '-') as gooddesc,
        coalesce(i.cdin_Customdeclar, '-') as custdec,
        coalesce(i.cdin_NoofPackages, 0) as pkg,
        coalesce(i.cdin_WT, 0) as wt, 
        coalesce(i.cdin_volumewt, 0) as vwt,
        coalesce(i.cdin_MortgageAmount, 0) as lcamt,
        coalesce(p.pinv_name, '-') as invno,
        coalesce(p.pinv_TotalAmount, 0) as invamt,
        p.pinv_Status, p.pinv_InvoiceProperty as prop,
        coalesce(c.comp_name, '-') as custname,
        coalesce(Comp_CompanyId, '-') as custid, 
        coalesce(c.comp_idcust, '-') as accpacno,
        coalesce(t.Terr_Caption, '-') as Terr,
        convert(nvarchar, '01', 2) as type     
    from 
        cdindex i 
    inner join   
        company c on i.cdin_CompanyId = c.Comp_CompanyId  
    inner join 
        Territories t on i.cdin_Secterr = t.Terr_TerritoryID 
    left outer join 
        PerformaInv p on i.cdin_cdindexid = p.pinv_CDIndexId 
    where
        (cdin_deleted Is null And c.comp_deleted Is null 
         And t.Terr_Deleted Is null And p.pinv_deleted Is null)
        and cdin_startunstufdate between @cdin_startunstufdate1 and @cdin_startunstufdate2
        and (p.pinv_status in ('Draft', 'Posted') or pinv_status is null) 
        and (p.pinv_InvoiceProperty = '01' or p.pinv_InvoiceProperty is null )
end
```

I want to call this proc using EF like this:

`var sp = db.select_alltypes(new DateTime (2016-07-01), new DateTime (2016-07-28)).ToList();`

Every time I call it with passing parameters, the debugger shows a runtime error.

But if I call it without parameters, with altering the stored procedure to be without parameters and give it specified date:

```
var sp = db.select_alltypes().ToList();
```

It returns the expected parameter.

The error is:

> Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command
>   definition. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Error converting data type datetime2 to datetime

Comment: can you look at the inner exception?

Comment: @gilmishal   By expanding the inner exception, the message i get is:
Error converting data type datetime2 to datetime.

Comment: Actually, if you copy/paste that inner exception to Google, you get your answer..

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['datetime2' error when using entity framework in VS 2010 .net 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586566/datetime2-error-when-using-entity-framework-in-vs-2010-net-4-0)

Comment: @uteist of course i did that but no solution.

Comment: @uteist i think that the format of the datetime i pass i wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the **OP's Feedback**.

No need to do any `datatype` change on the SQL table and Just 2 steps as below.

**step 1 :**

Change the `datatype` of the parameter on the SP to be like this:

`@cdin_startunstufdate1 DateTime2=null, @cdin_startunstufdate2 DateTime2=null`

**Step 2 :**

Sp call should be like this.

```
var sp = db.select_alltypes(DateTime.Parse("2016-07-01"),DateTime.Par‌​se("2016-
07-28")).To‌​List();
```

**Original Answer :**

Entity framework handles all the `dates` as a `Datetime2`,

**Problem :**

If your fields in the database are `Datetime`,then that can be a problem.

**Solution :**

You have to change the `cdindex` table's `cdin_startunstufdate` column date field datatype to `datetime2`.

***How to change the `datetime` to `dDatetime2`***

Just go to your SQL table's datetime column and change it as shown below.

[image]

**Update :**

Sp call should be like this.

```
var sp = db.select_alltypes(DateTime.Parse("2016-07-01"),DateTime.Par‌​se("2016-
07-28")).To‌​List();
```

Comment: Is there another solution,

Comment: it gives me error while executing it on sql 
`Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The index '_dta_index_Activity_7_2021582240__K11_9_10' is dependent on column 'acty_Login'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN acty_Login failed because one or more objects access this column.
`

Comment: I don't know what is the conversion to DateTime2 but i'm at work so what if someone wants to work on database using SQL server is there any issue to CRUD the Datetime column in any table ?

Comment: Sorry,I didn't get your point ?

Comment: Also After closing visual studio the same error occur.

Comment: That script won't work hence FK references. I have removed that.You have to do it manually.

Comment: how to change datetime to datetime2 manually.

Comment: i know that i asked you to help me many times, but really there's too much tables to change it's columns to DateTime2 so i noticed that there is another solution which is to convert it to nullable<dateTime>, do you know how to do this, i want a solution without modifying database.

Comment: You don't need to change all the tables.Just `cdindex` table's `cdin_startunstufdate` column.That is it.

Comment: when i try to edit the datatype it gives me the following error:
`Saving Changes isn't permitted`

Comment: you need to run the management studio as `Administrator` permission.

Comment: i already run with administrator, if you understand how to solve it using nullable<datetime> method? i want a solution without modifying database.

Comment: Ok,then see this :https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/956176

Comment: you cannot use other solution hence database first.

Comment: Ok, sir be patient i convert the datatype to Datetime2 now i want to pass the parameters, how to do this ?

Comment: what happened when you run your SP again ? Any errors again ?

Comment: Error converting data type datetime2 to datetime.
now the error is that the datetime2 can't be converted to datetime!?

Comment: please do this `@cdin_startunstufdate1 datetime2 = null,
    @cdin_startunstufdate2 datetime2 = null` on your SP.

Comment: it gives me no error at run time but no output appeared.

Comment: it looks like the parameter isn't  taken or something

Comment: can you run your SP directly on the SQL and see what is the output ?

Comment: it gives me the expected result which is a list of data from the joined tables , note that i used the following format to pass the parameters:
`exec select_alltypes '2016-07-01','2016-07-28'` , 
in VS i used to call the proc in this way:
`var sp = db.select_alltypes(new DateTime(2016-07-01),new DateTime(2016-07-28)).ToList();`

Comment: can you try like this `var sp = db.select_alltypes("2016-07-01","2016-07-28").ToList();`

Comment: sorry for delay, it gives me the error : cannot convert string to DateTime?

Comment: I found it :
` var sp = db.select_alltypes(DateTime.Parse("2016-07-01"),DateTime.Parse("2016-07-28")).ToList();`
Thank you very much for help. @Sampath

Comment: Well done.I'll update it :)

Comment: :) thxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Oh, notice that it doesn't matter to change the datatype in Table=>right click=>Design.
but you must change the datatype for parameter in Stored Procedure.

Comment: Sorry..Can you explain it bit.may be a code snippet ...Then I can update my answer.Hope it'll help someone else in the future.

Comment: Ok, in our attempts to solve the problem you mentioned that i should change the datatype of the Column: **cdin_startunstufdate**  from table name(which is cdindex) Design, to be DateTime2. 
but the following step only needed to solve the problem even if you don't change the datatype of the column in a table.

**This is the Basic Step** change the datatype of  the parameter procedure to be like this: `@cdin_startunstufdate1 DateTime2=null,
@cdin_startunstufdate2 DateTime2=null`.

and the second step:
`DateTime.Parse("2016-07-01"),DateTime.Parse("2016-07-28")`

Comment: Aha..Is that mean no need to change the table column type ? did you revert it to `datetime` again and tested ? but above your `sp` says `DateTime2=null`.Then why do we need that ?

Comment: i don't know how to explain it clearly but if there's any question please mention.

i will explain again:
to solve the problem there's two steps to be considered:
**firstly**
change the datatype of the parameter procedure to be like this: `@cdin_startunstufdate1 DateTime2=null, @cdin_startunstufdate2 DateTime2=null`

**Second**
`DateTime.Parse("2016-07-01"),DateTime.Parse("2016-07-28")`

Comment: yes that what i'm trying to say:
once you changed the datatype of the parameter in the proc no need to change it in the table column.
you only need to change the datatype to `DateTiome2=null` in the proc

Comment: One question. Did you revert the SQL table column name back to `datetime` and tested again ?

Comment: And i revert the column type to DateTime then i test it the result is Worked perfectly.

Comment: Aha..OK. I'll put your feedback also as 2nd option.Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Yes i revert the sql table, notice that for verifying purpose in my model.edmx only retrieve the stored procedures not the views or the Tables.

Comment: ur welcome, thanks for you.

Answer (score 2):

EF doesn't treat all datetimes as DATETIME2, it treats all out of bounds or uninitialized dates as datetime2. From what I understand using `Nullable<DateTime>` to represent uninitialized datetimes instead of `DateTime` should solve your problem.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: @FaresAyyad You probably are using code first approach and in your `Context` you have a field of type `DateTime` change it to `DateTime?` and it should solve your problem.

Comment: @uteist no i'm using DB first.

Comment: Well, still, please check your context for `DateTime` properties and convert them to being `nullable` *Edit: You could also check my comments on your first post as well.

Comment: @uteist Can you give me explanation of how to convert them to nullable ?

Comment: Can you show me the method signature ef generated?

Comment: @gilmishal sorry, what is the method signature?

Comment: the code that creates the method such as 
`public void Foo(){}`