# Azure Table DateTime filed gets null on retrieving the row

Tags: c#, .net, azure, cloud, azure-table-storage

alright , so when i select the row and want to do some logic with the time filed , i get the value of it as {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM} . while am very sure the data is NOT null.

even with the  storage explorer its not null , but in run time it is ?

[image]

any idea what is the issue !?

Comment: very hard to tell what the issue is without seeing code and or how you are getting the data .. please show how you are getting at the data as shown in the service explorer.. normally this looks like you are trying to create a new instance of DateTime for example try running this in a console app and you will see what I mean `var jackedDateTime = new DateTime();`

Comment: Possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586566/datetime2-error-when-using-entity-framework-in-vs-2010-net-4-0?

Comment: I retrieved a row on my side and I could get the Time field correctly. From the snapshot you provided, the format of Time field is curious and it should look like "2016-08-30T01:49:28.412Z" when you set Time as DateTime. Please try to capture the Network Package when you retrieve rows via Fiddler, in order to make sure the Time field is returned correctly.